# Joint pmf question

Tags: probability

5 transistors are in a bin, 2 are defective. Test 1 at a time until defective one removed.

Let N1 = # of tests made until 1st defective is identified.

N2 = # of additional tests made until 2nd defective is identified.

N1 = 1, 2, 3, 4

N2 = 2, 3, 4, 5

For P(2,3) I don't see why it's not $ \frac{3}{5}*\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{20} $

Answer (score 2):

Because it is $(3/5)(2/4)(2/3)(1/2)(1/1)$, good, bad, good, good, bad.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of N2 actually. How would you test something like P(2,5) then? From my understanding you'd run out of additional things to test

Comment: That's right. The probability that $N_1=2$ and $N_2=5$ is $0$. In general we have $\Pr(N_1=a\cap N_2=b)=0$ if $a+b\gt 5$.

Comment: So there are not terribly many cases to worry about, $(1,1)$ to $(1,5)$, $(2,1)$ to $(2,3)$, $(3,1)$ to $(3,2)$, and $(4,1)$.